# How to get the data from an array of urls with axios and promises

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-promise

I have this endpoint that gives me the info about a specific character, looks like this:

Endpoint: 
`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1`

that gives me back an object with the name of the chracter as well as other properies, one of those properties is called episode.

```
{
  name: 'Ricky',
  id: 1,
  episode: [...]
}
```

And the episode property contains an aray of urls that look like this:

```
[
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/1",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/2",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/3"
  ...
]
```

I know I should use Promise.all and somehow loop over these and then resolve them but I cant get it to work.

This is what I tried, but I dont know if its correct, and it always gives back a promise no matter how many times I do `.then`

```
let episodeResponses;

  const episodesResponses = Promise.all(character.episode.map(url => {
    return axios(url)
      .then(resp => episodeResponses = resp)
  }))

  episodesResponses.then(x => console.log(x))
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to do after you hit every endpoint in the array?

Comment: You don't need to declare `episodeResponses` or assign anything to it. `.then(resp => resp)` should work. When the promise `episodesResponses` resolves, `x` should give you the entire array of responses from the endpoint.

Comment: Hey did you try using axios.all ? https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: @Supercool.no ill check it out thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a simplified form, this API call will look something like this.

```
const episodes = [
    axios('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/1'),
    axios('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/2'),
    axios('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/3')
];

Promise.all(episodes).then((data) => {
  const episode1 = data[0];
  const episode2 = data[1];
  const episode3 = data[2];
});
```

Call `.then()` on `Promise.all` instead. Once all promises are resolved, then you will have access to your data.

```
// Create a promise using Promise.all().
const episodeResponses = Promise.all(character.episode.map(url => axios(url)));

// Access the response once all promises are resolved.
episodesResponses.then(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use .map on character.episode to return an array of promises instead of doing it by hand like in the const episodes you wrote? I guess yes.. ill try. thanks.

Comment: ahhh now i get it... thanks... I was not getting how all glued toghether, but now i see. thanks! :) apretiate!